# GUI Student Application Form

Tags: java, swing

I have created a Student Application Form with NetBeans. The form contains
`JTextFields, JRadioButtons, JComboBoxes, JTextArea, and two JButtons`, one is <kbd>SUBMIT</kbd> another one is <kbd>Reset</kbd> JButton.
Then I connect it to my MySQL DataBase.
After clicking on the <kbd>SUBMIT</kbd> `JButton` the data will be stored into the database. But the problem is that after clicking <kbd>SUBMIT</kbd> `JButton` the fields are not cleared.

I want the fields to be empty when the data has been entered.

Another problem is for `JCombobox`, I wrote code like this:

```
String ob1=(String) combobox1.getSelectedItem()//getting date
String ob2=(String) combobox2.getSelectedItem()//getting month
String ob2=(String) combobox3.getSelectedItem()//getting year
```

I want to store above ob1,ob2,ob3 in Date of birth format
like 30-mar-1991.

Answer (score 3):

First if you want to clear fields in swing, you can write your own `reset()` in that you should manually clear your fields, For example `JTextField`, `JTextField.setText("");`

For RadioButton, you can use `clearSelection()` for your `ButtonGroup`. Like this you should define it in your `reset()` method. When you perform action for `submit` button you can call your `reset()` in the `actionPerformed`, so that you can clear fields. You can use this `reset()` in your reset button actionPerformed.

Second if you want, date of birth format like 30-mar-1991, convert it into single string then you can use `SimpleDateFormat`, refer this link

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: isn't simpler to use JSpinner with SpinnerDateModel, previously upvoted

Comment: I haven't used JSpinner so far... After checking it i feel it would be a better choice....